Looking for an efficient (computerized) way to convert large ternary sequences into their decimal equivalents.
I am doing a project on Cantor Sets for my undergraduate and I need an efficient (computerized) way to convert large ternary expansions such as the following to their decimal equivalent.
$$0.200202020202022022020202202020220222202220200020222222002...$$
I've tried to do this in Maple, but I have only been able to use its 'base' converter for integers.

What is the purpose of the decimal representation? Ternary is a perfectly good base and shows the construction of the number explicitly. If you want to do computations with one or more numbers then you want to convert the ternary number into whatever the internal representation of your software is (probably not decimal).

# this maple program parses a base-3 string
# with optional embedded dot left-to-right and
# constructs the decimal fraction
str := "0.200202020202022022020202202020220222202220200020222222002";
val := 0 ; 
founddot := -1 ;
for i in str do
        if i = "." then
                founddot := 1 ;
        elif founddot >=0 then
                val := val+parse(i)/3^founddot ;
                founddot := founddot+1 ;
        else
                val := 3*val+parse(i) ;
        end if ;
        print(i,val,founddot,StringTools[IsPunctuation](i)) ;
end do:


Remove the ternary point and count the base $3$ digits in your string.  If there are $n$ digits, you can convert the string as an integer, then divide by $3^n$
